# Beginner level books on market economics

Tags: reference-request, stock-market, self-study

Which books can be recommended for a beginner with a strong math background, who wishes to learn how markets work, what is a stock, what is a bond, how to trade e.t.c. and has a minimal knowledge of economics?

Comment: For 'how to trade' you may want to consult money.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For introductory learning nearly any introductory economics textbook would do. For example, [Mankiw's 7th edition](http://www.cengage.com/search/productOverview.do?Ntt=Mankiw%7C%7C42577214915126807451484525927531744829&N=16&Ntk=APG%7C%7CP_EPI&Ntx=mode%2Bmatchallpartial) has a section on "How Markets Work" and "Saving, Investment, and the Financial System". The latter discusses stock and bonds.